# How to pass a value to index.html from component in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular2 project where `index.html` contains header bar. Other components will take care of logging in and displaying other stuff.

I have to show a logo in header bar which is present in `index.html` only if the user loggedIn. I'm setting a flag in `app.component.ts` if the user logged in. How to refer that flag in `index.html`?

```
<body>
    <div class="content-body">
        <header class="header">
            <div class="header-bar container">
                <div class="header-bar__main">
                    <div class="header-heading">
                        <h1 class="page-title">noHold Application</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="btn btn--small btn--icon ng-scope" title="Logout"><span class="icon-sign-out"></span></a> // this line should be displayed only if user logs in.
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content__main">
                <div class="container">
                    <app-root>Loading... </app-root>        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  static loggedIn = false;

  getLoggedIn() {
    return AppComponent.loggedIn;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Angular, it's a **best practice** to have **one single** bootstrap component (*`AppComponent` in many cases, as well as in your case*), and define other components (*such as header, menu's, page content, login status, etc*).

In this case, I suggest you to modify your `app.component.html`, and introduce child components using their own selectors. For instance:

**app.component.html**

```
<header></header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Contents of `HeaderComponent` are rendered using the `header` tag/selector whereas contents of navigated components (ex: `AboutComponent`) are rendered using the `router-outlet` tag/selector.

**header.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  public loggedIn = false;

  ...
}
```

**header.component.html**

```
  <header class="header">
    <div class="header-bar container">
      <div class="header-bar__main">
        <div class="header-heading">
          <h1 class="page-title">noHold Application</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="loggedIn">
        <a class="btn btn--small btn--icon ng-scope" title="Logout"><span class="icon-sign-out"></span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Take care to not couple your components. A component should not access properties of another component.
There is many ways to decouple components. In your case a good choice could be to share common data between components.

Here is a quick example of implementation.
Create a class that represents your user :

```
class User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  ...
}
```

Create a class that contains your user's session state :

```
class Session {
  user: User;
  isLogged: boolean;

  login(user: User) {
    this.user = user;
    this.isLogged = true;
  }
}
```

Then your configure your application module to inject an instance of the Session class as a singleton :

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    ...
    { provide: 'session', useValue: new Session() },
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
```

Now in all your components, your can inject your session. An exemple in the login component that sets the user when he authenticates :

```
@Component({
  ...
})
class LoginComponent {
  constructor(private session: Session) {
  }

  private login() {
    let user = ....;  // Retrieve user from backend service...
    this.session.login(user);
  }
}
```

And you can also use the session in your templates :

```
<div *ngIf="session.isLogged">
  <a class="btn btn--small btn--icon ng-scope" title="Logout"><span class="icon-sign-out"></span></a>
</div>
```